# Issue with Canvas and requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, oop, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm on the newer side of javaScript, although, I just completed a similar project, which is why this one has me stumped.  My previous project worked well, but I used all globals and the purpose of this project was to go completely OOP, but I encountered a problem early on where there seems to be an issue with my requestAnimationFrame.  I don't get it because it is clearly running as I can see the Y value of the particle change, but there's no animation, it just appears when requestAnimationFrame seems to decide on its own to stop.  I have the particle velocity (P.vy) set to something obnoxiously low to even keep th particle on the canvas, I'm not sure if it's related to the problem because I didn't have to use a ridiculous value on my last project like that.

I have one single particle currently that I want to float upwards.  End game it will be just one of an array of particles that will be the fire in the scene.

```
class Particle {
  constructor(context, width, height) {
    this.x = width / 2;
    this.y = height / 2;
    this.vx = 0;
    this.vy = -0.006;//I had to set like this to keep on the page
    this.radius = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
  }
  update() {
    this.y += this.vy;//change Y pos
  }
};

var App = {
  requestAnimationFrame: window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
    function(callback) { 
      return setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); 
    },
  canvas: document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx: canvas.getContext('2d'),
  P: null,//this will be our particle
  initialize: function() {
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.P = new Particle(this.ctx, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);//create particle
    this.draw();
  },
  draw: function() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(this.P.x,this.P.y,this.P.radius,0,2*Math.PI);//draw particle
    this.ctx.stroke()
    this.P.update();
    this.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw());
  }
};

App.initialize();
```

Here's my last project that was (close to) a success but with all globals: [Previous](http://codepen.io/SkiZer0/pen/VbjdWe)

Here's my current project/issue: [Current](http://codepen.io/SkiZer0/pen/VbQaoa?editors=0010)

Comment: [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) + why do attach rAF on your object like that ? It won't work and it's already global anyway.

Comment: ...Thanks for the feedback

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` requires a function reference, you are lucky there is no global draw function or it would recurse to a call stack overflow. Should be `requestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this))` or better `requestAnimationFrame(App.draw)`. BTW `App` should be `app` Upper case only if you use `new` to create. Also you are using a direct reference for `ctx : canvas.getContext("2d"`), and the line above you are using query to get the reference `canvas :document.getElementById("canvas")` and window is the default and is not required `window.innerWidth` is the same as `innerWidth`

Comment: Thank you so much for the great feedback.  This completely sorted me out, Paste comment to answer for upvote